# In Hive sql syntax day part of date

Tags: hiveql

In Hive SQL, I wanted to automate a report to pick up last days' data by comparing partition day field which already exist and here is my where clause for that.

partition_dt_day   = DAY(unix_timestamp(date_sub(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(),'yyyy-MM-dd'),1),'yyyy-MM-dd'))

Will this syntax work?

Comment: I did figure this one. I need to use the following instead.

Comment: This worked. partition_dt_day = DAY(date_sub(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(),'yyyy-MM-dd'),1)